# Include custom Product Fields in an email

Tags: commerce

I have added a new "Courses" Product Type that has a field called "Course Link". The store admin can add a url to this field and we want to email the value to the customer after they purchase.

I have a Rule to fire on "Completing the checkout process" with action "Send HTML e-mail" and the email includes the token [commerce-order:commerce_line_items]  This is all working except my "Course Link" field is not included in the email. I do not have a token for "Course Link" field listed to include in the email.

I do have the "Course Link" field included under "Product Types > Courses > Manage Display > Line Item". Not sure what that even does.

My question is what should I be looking at to do this.

1. Try to bring it into scope in my current emailing Rule? Possibly through a Component that loops through line items and provides a value back?
2. Add it in the View that drives the [commerce-order:commerce_line_items] token?
3. A module like Commerce Messages or Commerce Invoice Receipt?
4. Some other approach?

Answer (score 0):

The solution here ([Drupal Commerce - Add Product Fields to Cart Form through Line Items](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144602/drupal-commerce-add-product-fields-to-cart-form-through-line-items)) for adding Product Fields to the Cart View answered my question.

I edited the "Line Item" View to include my custom Product Field.  This is the View that drives the [commerce-order:commerce_line_items] token but per the answer linked above:

*For that you'll need to add I believe the "Commerce Line Item: Referenced Products" relationship in the view.*

You also need to give anonymous users the Permission "View own orders of any type" (I also gave them "View own Order Orders" but probably not needed) or the email says "No Line Items Found" for anonymous checkouts.